# Installation of re2 module in Python failed

Tags: python

```
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv
-O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/re2.cpp -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/re2.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
src/re2.cpp:201:29: fatal error: re2/stringpiece.h: No such file or directory
 #include "re2/stringpiece.h"
                             ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have previously done `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: Try installing `libre2-dev` before installing the python package for *re2*. Also note that this is not particularly programming related.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried as code it didn't allow me saying that I needed to give more explanation, which was in fact redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stupid of me. I needed to first install Google re2 from https://github.com/google/re2

Followed the README there to make and install. This installs the re2 headers into /usr/local/include/re2 on Ubuntu.

Then installation of re2 python wrapper works.

Answer (score 12):

On ubuntu it's the following command:

```
apt-get install libre2-dev
```

Comment: this solution works also for the case:  


`cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++`  
`_re2.cc:37:21: fatal error: re2/re2.h: No such file or directory`  
`#include <re2/re2.h>`
`compilation terminated.`
`error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Answer (score 4):

for fedora 23, just fire up this command on your terminal

```
dnf install re2 re2-devel
```